# Handle Polymorphic with StdDeserializer Jackson 2.5

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, jackson

I have three classes which inherits from a super class (SensorData)

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = SensorDataDeserializer.class)
public abstract class SensorData {

}

public class HumiditySensorData extends SensorData {
}

public class LuminositySensorData extends SensorData {
}

public class TemperatureSensorData extends SensorData {
}
```

I want convert a json input into one of this classes depending on a parameter. I'm trying to use Jackson StdDeserializer and I create a custom deserializer

```
@Component
public class SensorDataDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<SensorData> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3625068688939160875L;

    @Autowired
    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    private static final String discriminator = "name";

    public SensorDataDeserializer() {
        super(SensorData.class);
        SpringBeanProvider.getInstance().autowireBean(this);
    }

    @Override
    public SensorData deserialize(JsonParser parser,
            DeserializationContext context) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec();
        ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(parser);
        ObjectNode sensor = (ObjectNode) root.get("data");
        String type = root.get(discriminator).asText();
        Class<? extends SensorData> clazz = this.sensorManager
                .getCachedSensorsMap().get(type).sensorDataClass();
        if (clazz == null) {
            // TODO should throw exception
            return null;
        }
        return mapper.readValue(sensor.traverse(), clazz);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I determine the correct type to mapping the concrete class, the mapper call again to the custom StdDeserializer. So I need a way
to broke the cycle when I have the correct type. The stacktrace is the next one

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.hp.psiot.mapping.SensorDataDeserializer.deserialize(SensorDataDeserializer.java:38)
at com.hp.psiot.mapping.SensorDataDeserializer.deserialize(SensorDataDeserializer.java:1)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3532)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1868)
at com.hp.psiot.mapping.SensorDataDeserializer.deserialize(SensorDataDeserializer.java:47)
at com.hp.psiot.mapping.SensorDataDeserializer.deserialize(SensorDataDeserializer.java:1)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3560)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2660)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:205)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters    (AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:184)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:105)
```

An example of input

```
{
    "name":"temperature",
    "data": {
        "value":20
    }
}
```

I only include the stacktrace to show that the mapper is calling again to the deserializer. The reason for the nullPointerException is that when the second the ObjectMapper is called the input is

```
"value":20
```

So, An exception is threw because we don't have the information to determine the type and it doesn't check if the input is correct

I want to avoid using JsonSubTypes and JsonTypeInfo if it's posible.

Thanks in advance!

---

Partial solution

In my case the SensorData is wrapped in other class (ServiceData)

```
class ServiceData {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = SensorDataDeserializer.class)
    List<SensorData> sensors;

}
```

So, I get rid of JsonDeserializer in SensorData class and put it in the field avoiding the cycle. The solution isn't the best, but in my case it helps me. But in the case that the class isn't wrapped in another one we still have the same problem.

Note that if you have a Collection and you annotate with JsonDeserialize that field you have to handle all the collection. Here is the modification
in my case

```
 @Component
 public class SensorDataDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<List<SensorData>> {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 3625068688939160875L;

      @Autowired
      private SensorManager sensorManager;

      private static final String discriminator = "name";

      public SensorDataDeserializer() {
           super(SensorData.class);
            SpringBeanProvider.getInstance().autowireBean(this);
      }

      @Override
      public List<SensorData> deserialize(JsonParser parser,
                DeserializationContext context) throws IOException,
                JsonProcessingException {
           try {
                ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) parser.getCodec();
                ArrayNode root = (ArrayNode) mapper.readTree(parser);
                int size = root.size();
                List<SensorData> sensors = new ArrayList<SensorData>();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                     ObjectNode sensorHead = (ObjectNode) root.get(i);
                     ObjectNode sensorData = (ObjectNode) sensorHead.get("data");
                     String tag = sensorHead.get(discriminator).asText();
                     Class<? extends SensorData> clazz = this.sensorManager
                               .getCachedSensorsMap().get(tag).sensorDataClass();
                     if (clazz == null) {
                          throw new InvalidJson("unbound sensor");
                     }
                     SensorData parsed = mapper.readValue(sensorData.traverse(),
                               clazz);
                     if (parsed == null) {
                          throw new InvalidJson("unbound sensor");
                     }
                     sensors.add(parsed);
                }
                return sensors;
           } catch (Throwable e) {
                throw new InvalidJson("invalid data");
           }

      }
 }
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use `@JsonTypeInfo`? Polymorphic handling is the specific use case for it.

In this case, you would want to use something like:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.PROPERTY, property="name")
@JsonSubTypes({ HumiditySensorData.class, ... }) // or register via mapper
public abstract class SensorData { ... }

@JsonTypeName("temperature")
public class TemperaratureSensorData extends SensorData {
   public TemperaratureSensorData(@JsonProperty("data") JsonNode data) {
     // extract pieces out
  }
}
```

which would handle resolution from 'name' into sub-type, bind contents of 'data' as `JsonNode` (or, if you prefer can use `Map` or `Object` or whatever type matches).

Comment: Because I don't want to take care of putting @ JsonTypeName in all subtypes, but you help me, searching information about @ JsonTypeInfo I found that I can annotate a field with @ JsonDeserialize and avoid to put it in the superclasss, so I was able to broke the cycle, is not the best solution but It's valid enought for now.

Anyway thank you for the reply, It helps me a lot, i can't vote you up because I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Ok. Just for future reference, there is also a way to avoid use of `@JsonTypeName`, using `SimpleModule.registerSubtypes(NamedType... subtypes)` -- `NamedType` allows specifying name to use for subtypes. Just in case others might be looking for similar solution. Glad you got it resolved!